# Iptables + прокси

Tags: iptables, прокси

И так, имеем, типовую атаку на игровой сервер, с помощью прокси, тоесть один ip, несколько десятков или сотен прокси долбит по серверу. Как можно выловить\забанить такое чудо?

Comment: так ip один у нескольких десятков или сотен прокси?

Comment: Есть 1 PC, с него ведется атака, проксюшами

Comment: с помощью прокси он подключается на игровой сервер.

Comment: тогда мой ответ подходит

Comment: Мне нужно как то определить источник и заблокировать его...

Comment: в моём ответе последний комментарий всё решает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

К сожалению способа определить прокси это или нет, возможности нет, кроме HTTPS проксей, который иногда кидают хедеры. Вопрос древний, но вот так.

Answer (score 1):

```
iptables -A INPUT -s <source ip> -j DROP
```

Comment: Как дропнуть ip, я увы, знаю, а вот как узнать ip обидчика, нет.

Comment: вот так узнаете обидчика, если в <port> укажете порт    netstat -ntp | sed -E 's/^([^ ]*[ ]*){4}//;s/[ ].*$//' | grep ":80$" | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -1

Comment: наврал.. вот так надо    netstat -ntp | sed -E 's/^([^ ]*[ ]*){4}//;s/:[0-9]*[ ].*$//' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -1

Comment: Может, просмотрев видео, вы сумеете понять меня:http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SqALJYCB-rk

Comment: Не знаю что вы там пытаетесь грепом выцепить, но вот обычный лог:http://2paste.in/qdfp

Comment: вот ваш вывод моим "грепом" и пройдитесь, он покажет ip, с которого до вас больше всего коннектов. вообще для такого часто используют fail2ban.

Comment: проблема в том что он мне выводить один адрес 127.0.0.1 ...

Comment: тогда "| head -1" в конце уберите, увидите весь список.. хотя это может говорить о том, что iptables проблему не решит, так как локальных коннектов больше, значит отказ в сервисе находится уровнями выше (по модели ОСИ) и, соответственно, должен решаться там.